# i have many ifstatements, can i make it more compact and cleaner? C#

Tags: c#

this is my first thread here on Stackoverflow and what i know i havent seen a simular thread. And i only wana know if it's a way to make my code more compact and cleaner. What it's doing is rotate the firepoint and doing so my character can shoot a bullet the way its facing. (it's a top down game like The Binding of Isaac)

Thanks for any Suggestion in advance.

```
     if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1")) {

        if(animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("idle up"))
        {
            firePoint.Rotate(0,0,0);
            Attack();
        }
        else if(animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("up"))
        {
            firePoint.Rotate(0,0,0);
            Attack();    
        }
        else if(animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("idle right"))
        {
            firePoint.Rotate(0,0,-90);
            Attack();
            firePoint.Rotate(0,0,+90);
        }
        else if(animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("right"))
        {
            firePoint.Rotate(0,0,-90);
            Attack();
            firePoint.Rotate(0,0,+90);     
        }
        else if(animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("idle down"))
        {
            firePoint.Rotate(0,0,180);
            Attack();
            firePoint.Rotate(0,0,-180);
        }
        else if(animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("down"))
        {
            firePoint.Rotate(0,0,180);
            Attack();
            firePoint.Rotate(0,0,-180);     
        }
        else if(animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("idle left"))
        {
            firePoint.Rotate(0,0,90);
            Attack();
            firePoint.Rotate(0,0,-90);
        }
        else if(animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("left"))
        {
            firePoint.Rotate(0,0,90);
            Attack();
            firePoint.Rotate(0,0,-90);     
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could use a variable to store getCurrentAnimatorStateInfo. Also several of your blocks have the exact same rotate numbers. Could use the variable to say if(yourVar.isname("idle") || yourVar.isname("down"))

Comment: I recommend looking into [State Machines](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/state).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you could simplify it into something like this:

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
{
    var animatorStateInfo = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);
    if (animatorStateInfo.IsName("idle up") || animatorStateInfo.IsName("up"))
    {
        firePoint.Rotate(0, 0, 0);
        Attack();
    }
    else if (animatorStateInfo.IsName("idle right") || animatorStateInfo.IsName("right"))
    {
        firePoint.Rotate(0, 0, -90);
        Attack();
        firePoint.Rotate(0, 0, +90);
    }
    else if (animatorStateInfo.IsName("idle down") || animatorStateInfo.IsName("down"))
    {
        firePoint.Rotate(0, 0, 180);
        Attack();
        firePoint.Rotate(0, 0, -180);
    }
    else if (animatorStateInfo.IsName("idle left") || animatorStateInfo.IsName("left"))
    {
        firePoint.Rotate(0, 0, 90);
        Attack();
        firePoint.Rotate(0, 0, -90);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for ty <3

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessarily going to shrink things, but perhaps a list of names with the rotations/degrees might help simplify your logic to separate concerns.

```
private class RotationItem
{
    public string Name;
    public int[] Rotations;
}

private static IEnumerable<RotationItem> RotationMap = new []
{
    new RotationItem { Name = "up", Rotations = new [] { 0 } },
    new RotationItem { Name = "right", Rotations = new [] { -90, 90 },
    // ... etc...
}

private void MyFunction()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1")) 
    {
        val matchedRotationItem = RotationMap.firstOrDefault(r => animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName(r.Name) || animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("idle " + r.Name));
        if (matchedRotationItem != null)
        {
            foreach (var rotation in matchedRotationItem.Rotations)
            {
                firePoint.Rotate(0, 0, rotation);
                Attack();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code you have.

Pushing to minimise code can have the unwanted side-effects like

- Making it harder to maintain
- Being less explicit
- Less declarative

However, here is an example with a *local function* and *nesting reduction*.

```
if (!Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
   return;

var state = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);

void Local(int value, bool reverse, bool reset = true)
{
   firePoint.Rotate(0, 0, value * (reverse ? -1 : 1));
   Attack();
   if(reset) 
      firePoint.Rotate(0, 0, value * (reverse ? 1 : -1));
}

if (state.IsName("idle up") || state.IsName("up"))
   Local(0, reverse: false, reset: false);
else if (state.IsName("idle right") || state.IsName("right"))
   Local(90, reverse: true);
else if (state.IsName("idle down") || state.IsName("down"))
   Local(180, reverse: false);
else if (state.IsName("idle left") || state.IsName("left"))
   Local(90, reverse: false);
```

<sub>***Note** : I really **don't** suggest doing this, also this is untested so I may have made a mistake somewhere*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can use switch statements and fall through to group like items like below.

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1")) {

string IsName = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName;
 switch(IsName)
        {
case "idle up":
case "up":
            firePoint.Rotate(0,0,0);
            Attack();
break;
       case "idle right":
        case "right":
            firePoint.Rotate(0,0,-90);
            Attack();
            firePoint.Rotate(0,0,+90);
        break;
     case "idle down":
case "down":
            firePoint.Rotate(0,0,180);
            Attack();
            firePoint.Rotate(0,0,-180);
        break;
       case "idle left":
case "left":
            firePoint.Rotate(0,0,90);
            Attack();
            firePoint.Rotate(0,0,-90);
        break;
          }
}
```

Comment: this is really helpful for the future of my programming career to i appreciate the help :3

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using switch statements? A switch statement takes an integer and "switches" the outcome on a certain condition. Example:

```
switch(p) {
  case 1:
    printf("Hello, world!");
  case 2:
    printf("Goodbye, world!");
}
```

Comment: i can try that dont have that mutch experience but i will look it up thanks.

Comment: How about you actually post the code with switch statement and you may get some upvotes.

Comment: Ah, I don't care about stack overflow anymore... I'm not that qualified to help others anyway.